# How to make a function which can allow me to make elements and add them to an array?

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I am learning swift from the basics. So i was exercising my self by thinking of somethings and making it.

So earlier I wanted to make a function which would allow me to add elements of type "Int" in a tuple. Here is the code for that in swift 2.0 syntax which i made:

```
    func tupleMaker(t1 t1: Int, t2: Int) -> (tuple1: Int, tuple2: Int) {
         let tuples = (t1, t2)
         return  tuples

       }
```

So I wanted to know how to make a function which will allow me to me make and add elements to an array. The function above would only allow me to add 2 elements in it, so also tell me how can I add as many elements in the array and the tuple as I want.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can you be clearer? Do you want the create an array of tuples and a function that adds values to that array?

Comment: Let me make it clearer.

Comment: I want to make a function which will allow me to add values or elements into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var array: [(Int, Int)] = [] // Create an empty mutable array that contains a tuple of ints

func addToArray(inout array: [(Int, Int)], first: Int, second: Int) {
    let tuple = (first, second)
    array.append(tuple)
}

addToArray(&array, first: 1, second: 2)
addToArray(&array, first: 3, second: 4)

array // => [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

Comment: How about just array elements, without any tuples?

Comment: @YousufEjazi007 I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: In the solution you gave me, it adds tuples as individual elements to the array. But how can I add just numbers or Ints or doubles in the array only, without them being in a tuple?

Comment: Just use the `append` function. But be aware that arrays in Swift are typed, so you need to declare the types that it holds and only add values of that type.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Array {
    mutating func addElements(arguments: Element...)  {
        for arg in arguments {
            append(arg)
        }
    }
}


var myArray: [AnyObject] = []

myArray.addElements("Name")
myArray.addElements(45)
myArray.addElements(NSDate())
myArray.addElements("name2",25,NSDate())

myArray  // ["Name", 45, "Sep 30, 2015, 10:21 AM", "name2", 25, "Sep 30, 2015, 10:21 AM"]
```